# Installing mym to connect to mysql with matlab

Tags: mysql, matlab, zlib

After quite a bit of searching and trying different things, I am stumped on how to get mym to work (as found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mym/). I was wondering if anyone has a very simple list of actions needed to get this to work. I think my main trouble is installing zlib. I don't understand how to actually install it or work with it. I have tried to use Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010 but then only the debug versions are compiled. That means when I try to use the mex function in matlab it gives me the error:
Error: Could not detect a compiler on local system 
which can compile the specified input file(s) 
I just don't understand the process and everywhere I look it says something different. I have tried multiple versions of each all of the programs involved and nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

mex -setup

from the command line to define your compiler on your system. Once you do that then Matlab will correctly locate the compiler and build the mex libraries it needs.

See:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html